# How to copy one column into another new one properly(without copy error)?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to copy one column into a new one.
I use this code:

```
df['income10']=df['income'].copy(deep=False)
```

I get this error:

```
/Users/hairy/ipykernel/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

By adding shallow copy I thought I would've prevented the error.

Comment: Your df is a subset from another dataframe right ?

Comment: Use `df = df.assign(income10 = df.income)`. It will create a new object which wont be a reference. Then again, might be best to fix the problem further up in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this way:

```
df['income10']=df.loc[:, ['income']]
```

Comment: I still get SetWithCopyWarning from this.

Comment: What is the version of pandas you are using?

Comment: pd.__version__ : '0.24.0'

Comment: mine is 0.22.0 and it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

I reran the whole Jupyter notebook and it worked for some reason.